# Python Syntax Error on Line 37

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to program Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python.
I'm using Python 2.7.6, on Linux Mint 17.2, through the Terminal. I have an x86_64 machine.
I keep getting a syntax error that says this:

```
  File "rockpaperscissors.py", line 37
    while playerDecision == not 1 or == not 2 or == not 3:  # It makes the player choose rock, 1, paper, 2, or scissors, 3.
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my code:

```
import random

gameContinue = True # The game will repeat until the player decides to stop playing.
playerContinue = "Nothing" # This is the choice that the player makes if it wants to keep playing or not. If it has a valid value, it gets rolled down to gameContinue.
playerDecision = 0 # The player has not made a decision yet, so it is set to a default value, 0.
playerScore = 0 # The player has not done anything, so it is set to 0.
playerWin = False # The player has not done anything, so it has not won yet.

botDecision = 0 # The bot has not made a decision yet, so it is set to a default value, 0.
botScore = 0 # The bot has not done anything, so it is set to 0.
botWin = False # The bot has not done anything, so it has not won yet.

def botChoice():
    botDecision = random.randint(1, 3) # The bot makes a random decision, for rock, paper, or scissors.

def checkPlayerDecision():
    if playerDecision == 1 and botDecision == 2: # If the player has rock, and the bot has chosen paper, the bot wins.
        return 2
    elif playerDecision == 1 and botDecision == 3: # If the player has rock, and the bot has chosen scissors, the player wins.
        return 1
    elif playerDecision == 2 and botDecision == 1: # If the player has paper, and the bot has chosen rock, the player wins.
        return 1
    elif playerDecision == 2 and botDecision == 3: # If the player has paper, and the bot has chosen scissors, the bot wins.
        return 2
    elif playerDecision == 3 and botDecision == 1: # If the player has scissors, and the bot has chosen rock, the bot wins.
        return 2
    elif playerDecision == 3 and botDecision == 2: # If the player has scissors, and the bot has chosen paper, the player wins.
        return 1
    else: # If any of the above conditions have not been met, no one wins.
        return 0

while gameContinue:
    botChoice() # The bot makes a random decision, for rock, paper, or scissors.

    print "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!"
    print "Choose rock, paper, or scissors."
    while playerDecision == not 1 or == not 2 or == not 3:  # It makes the player choose rock, 1, paper, 2, or scissors, 3.
        print "Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3"
        playerDecision = int(raw_input())

    if checkPlayerDecision() = 1: # If the player wins, the playerScore is increased by 1, the player wins, and the bot loses.
        playerScore += 1
        playerWin = True
        botWin = False
    elif checkPlayerDecision() = 2: # If the bot wins, the botScore is increased by 1, the player loses, and the bot loses.
        botScore += 1
        playerWin = False
        botWin = True
    else: # Otherwise, no one wins.
        playerWin = False
        botWin = False

    if playerWin == True: # If the player wins, it says so, and the scores are listed.
        print "The player wins!"
        print "Player: " + playerScore
        print "Bot: " + botScore
    elif botWin == True # If the bot wins, it says so, and the scores are listed.
        print "The bot wins!"
        print "Player: " + playerScore
        print "Bot: " + botScore

    while playerContinue == not "True" or == not "False": # This makes the player choose if it wants to continue.
        print "Want to keep playing?"
        print "True for Yes, False for No"
        playerContinue = str(raw_input())

    if playerContinue == "False": # If the player has chosen to not keep playing, the gameContinue turns false, and the program exits.
        gameContinue = False

    playerContinue == "Nothing" # playerContinue is set to "Nothing" so the player can be asked to continue later.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: what are you expecting `playerDecision == not 1` to do?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Conditional_Statements#If_statements

Comment: Research things! `not equals` is written as `!=` in Python not `== not`.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `playerDecision == not 1` was a valid Python construct?

Answer (score 1):

`not` is for the logical inverse, like a NOT logic gate. `not True` evaluates to `False`, and `not False` evaluates to `True`. `not 3` evaluates to False.

Instead of `== not 3` your probably want `!= 3`. You should be using `and` instead of `or`, and can't make multiple comparisons in that way, so you could use:

```
while playerDecision != 1 and playerDecision != 2 and playerDecision != 3:
```

A cleaner way is to use `in`:

```
while playerDecision not in (1, 2, 3):
```

The same sort of change should be made to the `playerContinue` while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop to:

```
while playerDecision not in [1, 2, 3]:
    # your code here

while playerContinue not in ["True", "False"]:
    # your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong. The way you do what you're trying to accomplish:

`while playerDecision is not 1 or while playerDecision is not 2...`

Which is equal to:

`while playerDecision != 1 or playerDecision != 2...`.

However in your case, when there are multiple conditions, better code it like so:

`while playerDecision not in [1, 2, 3]:`